# MBP M2 regularly loses network connection

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network

I have a M2 MBP which Im having some issues with.

Under normal operation, it will connect to a wifi network with no issues - DHCP will assign an IP, DNS and router.

Every now and then, it suddenly drops the DHCP info, leaving me with no IP address, DNS servers or routing, and nothing I can do will get it working again on DHCP until it sorts itself out.

The MBP is connected to the wifi network, it just wont talk to the DHCP server.

It can remain in this state for several minutes before correcting itself - or I can set a manual IP address and Im back on the network immediately.  Sometimes a reboot also fixes it, but not always.

I have his issue on multiple wifi networks that have nothing in common apart from this laptop - it even happens on my iPhones hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue from a network testing MacBook. All the system was blocked, and the MB was running hot, even when closed. I was at the Genius Bar for it. Later I found this solution:

Go to System Settings > Network and here please remove all USB 10/100/1000 LAN X - were X stands for a number. I have had until 27. Remove all of them. You even may remove the one without an additional number. (Click on them with CTRL to remove them)

Please check also your WIFI connections. Remove all wich are old. If you have more than 20 connections, you should start to purge them. And most important: remove the actual WIFI connection and recheck in with your Router PW.

Hope this helps

marek